# How to add a welcome voice to the blog?

Tags: javascript, audio, blogger

I want when people visit my blog, they will hear a welcome voice from my blog. does anyone know how to add welcome voice?
All over the internet are welcome messages, not voices.

Comment: Why? Completely annoying and that is why browsers are now preventing auto play of audio

Comment: i just wanna try. in certain areas being greeted with a voice is not a bad thing.

Comment: You can use javascript for this work

Comment: yes, but how? I wouldn't have asked if I had known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this tag in html file :-

```
<audio id="music" src="music.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>
```

and in your script

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("music").play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play an audio file like this:

```
let audio = new Audio('path/to/your/file.pm3');
audio.play();
```

As already mentioned in the comments of your question, modern browsers usually block autoplay. You can't just start playing audio as soon as your page is loaded, the user needs to interact with your page (e.g. click something) before the play() method can be called.